# How do I get rid of Google penguin?

Tags: google, google-penguin-algorithm

My site is affected by google penguin, traffic on my site down, missing keywords on search engines. Please help me get rid of this algorithm

Comment: We need more information about your website, without it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: "I did something wrong and I don't want to feel the consequences!".......great attitude right there.

Comment: @patricksweeney I like the quote "Please help me get rid of this algorithm" I was going to comment earlier that if they want to get rid of penguin to call the riddler or ask batman for help lol....

Comment: @Anagio what's even worse than that is that 2 other people favorited this question as if it has any value whatsoever.

Comment: _Please help me get rid of this algorithm_ Thanks for the comedy, it made my day <grin>. Hacking Google is not an option...

Answer (score 2):

In order to "get rid" of it you have to understand what algorithm hit you and why. Take a look [at some algorithm changes here](http://www.seomoz.org/google-algorithm-change). You should make use of the Google and Bing Webmastertools and look for hints, warnings and errors.

If it is really related to your content (quality and quantity, uniqueness, authority, usefullness ...) or your backlink profile, you can try to change it to the better.

Please take a look at [this question and answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35331/what-constitutes-a-substantial-good-faith-effort-to-remove-the-links/35340#35340) on the same or similar topic.

I provided these links:

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/recovery-from-google-penguin-tips-from-the-trenches

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/penguins-pandas-and-panic-at-the-zoo

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-wpmuorg-recovered-from-the-penguin-update

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Penguin is supposed to repair the effects of improper ranking due to obscure techniques, we can assume that the algorithm thinks that you have done something wrong.

If you have used any tactic considered 'black-hat', then you can start by undoing that. If you haven't then you should read the links provided by initall and also check the links provided [in this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin).

Answer (score 0):

Penguin is all about web spamming. In my view first you should remove your spam links. If spma links like article and directory van not be removed, then you can directly remove it by a tool of Google in Google webmaster i.e. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main